# SQL - How to select when a date is a Monday OR the first date in the table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of sales reports (eod_cache).  I'm trying to get a list of each week of sales, beginning with Monday, OR if the first date of sales is not a Monday, then adding that to the list as well.  For example, if there are daily sales starting on 7/20/2011 through today, the list would be:

```
7/25/2011
7/20/2011
```

I am currently getting just Mondays, and wondering how I can add the minimum/smallest date to my list of returned dates.  Here is my statement:

```
SELECT      DISTINCT date
FROM        eod_cache
WHERE       DAYOFWEEK(date) = 2
ORDER BY    date DESC
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an `OR` condition to your `DAYOFWEEK` criteria that also allows in the smallest date.

```
SELECT      DISTINCT date
FROM        eod_cache
JOIN        user_store_permissions
ON          user_store_permissions.store_id = eod_cache.store_id
WHERE       user_store_permissions.user_id = 32 AND
            (DAYOFWEEK(date) = 2 or date = (select min(date) from eod_cache))
ORDER BY    date DESC
```

In this example, I'm just using the smallest date in the table itself, though it looks like you might want to modify that query to use your permissions infrastructure, but that modification should be self-explanatory.

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't think to use a sub-query in that manner.  I modified the sub-query to use my permissions joined as you recommended and it works.

Comment: @Kyle: Great to hear! Please be sure to mark this as the answer if it took care of your question.